# Create a new VHD and mount it without DiskManagement window popup with Powershell

Tags: powershell, vhd, automount

How can I create and mount a new VHDX volume without a drive letter assigned?
On some servers I get the behaviour described below, on others it works like it should.
So there must be a system setting which affect this behaviour besides AutoMount.

I use the following code to create and mount a VHDX volume with Powershell

```
New-VHD -path $vhdpath -SizeBytes $vhdSize -Dynamic | `
Mount-VHD -NoDriveLetter -Passthru
```

This creates the VHDX file and mounts ist into the system.
Then the DiskManagement window popus up instantly, asking me to initialize the new volume.
But I want to initialize, partition and format the volume using scripting.

I found hints to [disable the windows AutoMount](https://dereknewton.com/2010/11/turning-off-automount-in-windows/) feature, but this did not help.

Also the system assigns a random drive letter to the volume when I manuall abort the initializing dialog and proceed with the following commands:

```
$d = InitializeDisk -Number 4 -PartitionStyle GPT
$p = New-Partition -DiskNumber $d.Number -UseMaximumSize -AssignDriveLetter:$False
$v = Format-Volume -Partition $p -FileSystem NTFS -Confirm:$false
Add-PartitionAccessPath -DiskNumber $d.Number -PartitionNumber $p.PartitionNumber -AccessPath "C:\mount"
```

Then the partition is created and mounted into C:\mount.
But the system also assigns a drive letter. I do not want this.

System: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
Shell:  Powershell 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem for myself now.
There was the [USB Drive Letter Manager Service](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html) running on the server which showed the suspect behaviour.

Now I stop this service before I create and mount the VHD and start it afterwards again.